# How to analyze non-normal DVs from two-way repeated measures (4x4) design

Tags: repeated-measures, normality-assumption, two-way

In my study twenty subjects experienced all four levels of both factors (4x4 design). The residuals for my DVs were not normally distributed as would be required for the two-way repeated measures ANOVA.

- How should I proceed?
- With my sample size would removing outliers be unwise?
- If I transform the data how can I find a transformation that is appropriate for all of the combinations of factor levels (4x4=16)?
- Whichever direction I take, do I need to have normally distributed data in all 16 combinations of factor levels?

If anyone could point me in the right direction or suggest reading material that would be greatly appreciated.